# Underscore weird behaviour during string concatenation

Tags: javascript, string, underscore.js

I'm doing a quite simple string interpolpation with underscore.js :

```
_.each(data, function(book){
    $('#booksList').append("<li>" + book.title + "</li><li><img src='" + book.cover + "'</li>" )
});
```

I cant understand why this appears in my DOM :

```
<img li="" <="" src="imageUrl.jpg">
```

Comment: Seems like you're missing a `>` after `book.cover + "'`. It's supposed to be `book.cover + "'></li>"`

Comment: Thanks ! You're the best :) spend too much time watching this line I guess :)

Comment: Copy paste your comment in an answer so I can validate it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're missing a `>` after `book.cover + "'`. It's supposed to be `book.cover + "'></li>"`.